# How to skip certain columns when setting formatting style while exporting to excel using Apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, javafx, apache-poi

I have table with 12 columns and i want to set thousand separator and two decimals starting from column 4. This is how i set values in table:

```
Cell cell = null;
for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
    HSSFRow hssfRow = hssfSheet.createRow(i + 3); // skipping title                                 
    for (int col = 0; col < tableView.getColumns().size(); col++) {
        Object celValue = tableView.getColumns().get(col).getCellObservableValue(i).getValue();
        try {
            if (celValue != null) {
                cell = hssfRow.createCell(col);
                cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(celValue.toString()));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            hssfRow.createCell(col).setCellValue(celValue.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am setting thousand separator and two decimals like this:

```
cell.getCellStyle().setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0.00"));
```

So the result is thousand separator and two decimals on whole table. Is there a way to set formatting only after certain column?

Comment: where's the problem, exactly? set the format only for the cells you want to (hint: translate _starting from column 4_ to a condition inside your loop :) BTW, that's plain java, unrelated to neither javafx nor poi, maybe time for learning some java language basics?

Comment: @kleopatra Don' insult me, i did try that. But it always format whole table regardless if `col` starts from 0 or 4. Something else is wrong.

Comment: _i did try that_ not in the snippet you are showing: you loop across all table columns from 0 on .. and there cannot be any insult in stating facts ;) Anyway, time for a [mcve] to clarify what _exactly_ you are doing.

Comment: @kleopatra I solved it. THANK YOU FOR BEING SO FREINDLY AND HELPFUL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
DataFormat format = hssfWorkbook.createDataFormat();
HSSFCellStyle styleForTotal2 = hssfWorkbook.createCellStyle();
styleForTotal2.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#,##0.00"));
```

Format above is working fine, it only format columns that i want.

For loop:

```
for (int col = 4; col < tableView.getColumns().size(); col++) {
    Object celValue = tableView.getColumns().get(col).getCellObservableValue(i).getValue();
    try {
        if (celValue != null) {
            Cell = hssfRow.createCell(col);
            Cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(celValue.toString()));
            Cell.setCellStyle(styleForTotal2);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        hssfRow.createCell(col).setCellValue(celValue.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: glad you finally saw your error :) Now stick to java naming conventions, please